# Fetch links having no href attribute : Selenium-Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I am currently trying to crawl using ***selenium-python*** through an entire website with a specified crawl depth. I started with [Google](http://www.google.com) and thought of moving forward by crawling with it and simultaneously develop the code.

> The way it works is: If the page is 'www.google.com' and has 15 links within it, once all the links are fetched, it is stored in a dictionary with 'www.google.com' as the key and a list of 15 links as value. Then each of the 15 links are then taken from the corresponding dictionary and the crawling continues in a ***recursive*** manner.

The problem with this is that it moves forward with respect to the **href** attribute of every links found on a page. But not every links will have href attribute.

> For example: As it crawled and reached the [My Account Page](https://myaccount.google.com/?pli=1) it has **Help and Feedback** in it's footer which has an outerHTML of `<span role="button" tabindex="0" class="fK1S1c" jsname="ngKiOe">Help and Feedback</span>`.

So what I am not sure is that - what can be done on such a context where a link is highly supported by javascript/ajax for it matters - as it does not have a link but opens up a modal window/dialog box or sorts.

Answer (score 0):

> You might need to find a pattern of design for links. For eg: you
>   could have a link with anchor tag and in your case span.

It depends on the design of the webpage. How the developers intent do design the html elements through attributes/ identifiers.

For eg: if the dev decides to have a common class value for all the links that are not with the anchor tag name, it would be easy to identify all those elements.

> You could also try writing a script to fetch all the elements with the
>   expected tag name( for eg : span) here and try clicking on the
>   elements. You could fetch the details of the backend response/log
>   details. So for those, clicks, where you are getting additional
>   response/log would mean that it has an additional code written behind
>   giving us an idea that it is not a static element.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the issue I'm dealing with is to generalize the concept rather than dealing with each case individually. So what I am currently planning is to move forward with different websites to check they have coded and write accordingly. I know this idea is completely absurd. But unless a good plan/idea comes my way will be moving forward with it.